# Ввести список через пробел

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как ввести список через пробел?
Например: 1 2 3 4 5 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда нужно получить список чисел от пользователя, я обычно делаю так:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать следующую форму записи:

```
lst = input().split(';') # где ; - это разделитель (по умолчанию разделитель - пробел)
# 1.1;qwerty;2;teststr;3.2;lol
print(line)
# ['1.1', 'qwerty', '2', 'teststr', '3.2', 'lol']
```

Эта запись вернёт вам объект типа list, разделённый по точке с запятой. Как вернуть список, разделённый по пробелам, я думаю догадаться не сложно.

Также вы можете использовать регулярные выражения:

```
import re
lst = re.findall(r'\w+') #также подойдёт паттерн '\S+'
```

Ну а для более точного совпадения можно написать такой паттерн:

```
r'[^ ]+' # всё, кроме пробела
```

Вообще, регулярные выражения мощный инструмент. Рекомендую вам если не глубоко освоить, то хотя бы базово ознакомиться с ним.

Надеюсь, смог помочь. Всего доброго!

Answer (score -1):

```
def foo():
    inp = list(input('Enter list: '))
    print(inp)
```

Запускаем функцию видим:

```
Enter list:
```

Вводим:

```
123456
```

Получаем:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

По замечаниям из комментариев вот еще 1 вариант:

```
def foo_2():
    inp = input('Enter list: ')
    print(inp.split(' '))
```

Вводим:

```
5,1 5,51 5.555
```

Получаем:

```
['5,1', '5,51', '5.555']
```

Comment: Как вводить двух/трехзначные/n-значные числа?

Comment: Можно просто `inp.split()` тогда между числами может быть сколько угодно пробельных символов.