# Ввод чисел через пробел

Tags: python

Вводится список в виде целых чисел в одну строчку через пробел. С помощью цикла for необходимо найти наименьшее четное значение этого списка. Полученный результат выводится на экран. Если четного значения нет, выведите слово "None" (без кавычек). Реализовать приложение без использования функции min.

У меня возникла проблема с пробелом, не могли бы Вы мне подсказать как в этот код внедрить чтобы числа вводились через пробел?

```
n = int(input('Сколько чисел?  '))
print("Введите эти числа: ")
m =int(input())
x = 1
for i in range (n-1):
    a =int(input())
    if a< m and a % 2 == 0:
        m = a
if m and m % 2 == 0:
    print ('Минимальное парное число =', m)
else:
    print ('None')
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/649828/

Comment: @CameL выводит ошибку в a =int(input())

Comment: Смотрите принятый ответ по той ссылке

Comment: @CrazyElf все равно выводит ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Принять числа через пробел можно через input().split(), а потом через map, перевести в число и добавить в список. Вот так:

```
nums = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

А поиск наименьшего четного числа лучше делать так:

```
min = list1[0] #Обьявльем переменную, в котором будем хранить наименьшее число 
for i in range(len(list1)):
   if i % 2 == 0 and i < min: #Если число четное, и меньше min
      min = list1[i] #присваиваем min новое значение

if min % 2 != 0:
   print("None")
else: print(f"Наименьшее четное число {min}")
```

Comment: в задаче четко указано, что числа вводятся в одну строчку через пробел.